# Mouse cursor SPEED in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, speed, cursor

Is there any way to change the **speed** of your mouse cursor in Ubuntu?
(Please read the entire post before answering or marking this as duplicate...)

- I know about the menu in *System Settings > Mouse and Touchpad*:
  This only lets you config mouse *acceleration* and the *acceleration-threshold* (the latter is misleadingly labelled 'sensitivity'). The acceleration will speed up the cursor as it moves over the screen, the acceleration-threshold sets the limit for how far the cursor has to move until acceleration kicks in.
- I also know about the `xset X Y` command; this lets you set the exact
  same values as above (This can already be useful as the sliders in
  the menu actually only accept fixed values although it looks in the
  GUI as if they would accept all values out of a range...).

Please do *not* suggest any further options that modify acceleration. I am not interested in that feature, I personally think it makes the mouse behave sluggish, weird and unpredictable. What I'am looking for is sharp, responsive and quick(!) mouse cursor movement.

---

*Background:*
This is a problem since at least 11.10 and it is still a problem in 12.04 (I have both of these systems up and running on different machines.). I have tried both versions with a mouse that lets you increase sensitivity/speed (not acceleration/threshold thingy) via button on the device and the result is exactly what I wanted - but I do not have such mice available at all times and still want my systems mice to behave in a more or less acceptable way...

Answer (score 1):

**man mousedrv** shows a sensitivity option, but warns that all pixels will not be accessible if you use a value bigger than 1.

Your other options are to use the xset command or a higher resolution mouse.